# Update row numbering of the header and footer rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2016

Can anyone please let me know about any logic that I can use to update the row numbers of the header and footer rows in such a way that the header always has the min row number of a specific group and the footer always has the max row number of a the same group.

In this example attached, the first header and footer belong to the first group and so on. Can this be done by just using a self join ?

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFZFB.png)

Comment: Can anyone please advise on this ?

Comment: What query are you using to generate the output you posted?